# how to store all employee names in single textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

While working on this code I am getting single EmployeeName in textbox but instead of that I want all Employee Names from dataset in single textbox.Thanks for help.

```
public void loadnow()
{

    cn = new SqlConnection(str);
    cn.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("select EmployeeName=[EmployeeFirstName]+' '+[EmployeeLastName] from EmployeeMaster ", cn);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {

        foreach (DataRow myRow in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["EmployeeName"].ToString());
            sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
            TextBox1.Text = sb.ToString();

        }

        cn.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public void loadnow()
{
    cn = new SqlConnection(str);
    cn.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("select EmployeeName = [EmployeeFirstName] + ' ' + [EmployeeLastName] from EmployeeMaster", cn);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (DataRow myRow in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            sb.Append(myRow["EmployeeName"].ToString());
            sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
        }

        TextBox1.Text = sb.ToString();

        cn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: the solution is working but all time same employee is display in each row in textbox

Comment: that was your mistake, I just copied the code and provided the solution of the problem you mentioned, but I have fixed it now, try this.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
 TextBox1.Text += sb.ToString();
```